# get only specific data in success message from ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have an ajax call and i am getting a response from the call. the code is like this:

```
<div id="flow_#id#~#sid#" style="margin: 0 10px 0 0;float:right;height:150px;"  class="code"> 
                <img src="/assets/codes/#code#.jpg" style="max-height: 230px;">
            </div>
```

What i am doing is the response i get from my ajax, i want to replace the contents of the div tag with the value coming from my ajax success

ajax call is like this

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'bc.cfm?ID=' + getID + '&ssID=' + getSID,
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                $("#flow_" + getID + "~" + getSID + " img:last-child").remove();
                $("#flow_" + getID + "~" + getSID).html(data);
            }
        });
```

But a complete html page is coming in success, i can the img in firebug, but a complete html source is there, how can i extract that img tag and replace with the one which is already there above [the id is going to be same for both for identification, only 1 will be used, we will be removing and adding again]

Comment: what do you see when you go to `http://your-server:your-port/bc.cfm?ID=' + getID + '&ssID=' + getSID` ? Is this an image or a whole HTML?

Comment: whole html code, and i see image in the response tab of firebug and html in html tab

Comment: In that HTML, try finding the URL of that image you are interested in. That is the URL you should get via Ajax. I guess you know it but doesn't hurt to say: right click the image and choose "inspect" then find the `src` attribute of the `<img>` tag.

Comment: through jquery i should find

Comment: in firebug, what does it show as the response type of your ajax call?

Comment: are you expecting the whole html page or just the img in response ?

Comment: What does `~` in `$("#flow_" + getID + "~" + getSID ...` mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just extract image from the response, you can try this. I have not tested the code, but it should work. Please check it.

```
success: function(data){

            // get the image tag from the response
            var $img = $(data).find('img');

            $("#flow_" + getID + "~" + getSID + " img:last-child").remove();

            // replace 
            $("#flow_" + getID + "~" + getSID).html($img.html());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **JSON** instead

for example:

javascript

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST', 
    url: 'yourphpfile.php', 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (x) {                
      console.log(x.imgtag); // img
    }
  });
  return false;
```

php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$output=array(); 
$output['imgtag']='<img src="myimg.jpg">';       
echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

Place whatever you want into the $output array (such as img tags) and you may easily access it in JavaScript.